# C# - Calling BeginInvoke on a control fails to call the delegate

Tags: c#, multithreading, begininvoke

I am faced with an interesting issue that happens on Windows 8.1 while the application runs fine on Windows 7. The problem happens when we call BeginInvoke on a control to switch the execution to the UI thread that created the control in order to perform some UI updates.

Please see the sample code below.

```
private void RequestReportInfoCompleted(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    if (_synchronizer.InvokeRequired)
    {
        _synchronizer.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallBack(RequestReportInfoCompleted), new object[] { asyncResult });
            return;
    }
    //some code to be executed on the UI thread
}
```

_synchronizer is a user control that, I believe, is fully created at the time of call. Calling IsHandleCreated on the control returns true. Also the BeginInvoke call does not throw an exception, it goes through as it should but the delegate is never called.
I fixed the problem by passing a SynchronizationContext object from the thread that created the control and replacing the code above with calling Post on this object (with the same parameters) and that worked properly.

```
private void PostRequestReportInfoCompleted(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    //when returning from webservice you're in another thread. call the method below on original thread
    SynchronizationContext.Post(RequestReportInfoCompleted, asyncResult);
}

private void RequestReportInfoCompleted(object result)
{
    //some code to be executed on the UI thread
}
```

I would be interested if anyone knows if there is a difference in how windows in Windows 8.1 behave compared to Windows 7 that might cause this behavior.

We have a number of similar calls in our application that happen close to each other (calls to a web service that return on a different thread and need to be switched to the UI thread for updates) and an interesting fact is that if I switch the first call to using the SynchronizationContext object all the other calls work fine in the current implementation. In other words the control starts processing messages after the first successful call, while if the first call fails all subsequent calls will fail.

Any idea will be useful. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Try (just for debugging purposes) to replace BeginInvoke with Invoke, if something will happen asynchronously during invocation (but outside your delegate) you should see it

Comment: `SynchronizationContext.Post` works and `_synchronizer.BeginInvoke` doesn't works ? `SynchronizationContext.Post` internally uses `Control.BeginInvoke`; it shouldn't be like that. Can you try changing `_synchronizer.BeginInvoke` to `YourMainForm.BeginInvoke` and see if that works? Also posting some minimal repro will be massively helpful.

Comment: If it were the case that the window handle hadn't been created at the time `RequestReportInfoCompleted()` is called then `InvokeRequired` would return false. Just to be sure, I suggest adding a `Trace.WriteLine()` after `if (_synchronizer.InvokeRequired)` to verify that it isn't going past the `if`.

Comment: There are *two* threading races in your code.  One between InvokeRequired and BeginInvoke, another in the invoke queue implementation which throws away invoke requests for disposed controls.  SynchronizationContext.Post() gives better odds, that only stops working when the UI thread terminates.   At which point you don't care anymore.

Comment: @Adriano Repetti - replacing BegineInvoke with Invoke blocks the calling thread but the delegate is also never called, so the application locks up.

Comment: @Matthew Watson - the control actually goes past the if statement, in and out of BeginInvoke, hits the return and the calling thread continues execution. The delegate, supposedly pushed to the invoke queue, is never processed and executed by the UI thread.